# Reaching the parent's parent in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have a tkinter app with the following layout.

[image: Tkinter App Layout]

I have used an object-oriented hierarchical model such that the classes are instantiated like this:

```bash
MainWindow
├── OptionsFrame
│   ├── DataFrame
│   ├── MetaFrame
│   └── SaveFrame
└── PlotFrame
```

I want to be able to use the plot button within the SaveFrame to run a function which will plot using a FigureCanvasTkAgg canvas object.

I am struggling to see how I can reach the PlotFrame from within the SaveFrame.

So far I have been using a `main` parameter in my class declarations, i.e.

```py
class SaveFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, *args, **kwargs)
        self.main = main
```

which will allow me to go up one level of the hierarchy to the OptionsFrame, but what I need to do is go from

SaveFrame -> OptionsFrame -> MainWindow -> PlotFrame

I don't really know how this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: So you've actually described exactly what you need to do. Make sure you have a `main` attribute for each class (which declares the widget's parent), and you can trace through those to reach `MainWindow`. After you get to the parent, you should be able to adjust `PlotFrame`, through the instance that is probably declared in there.

Comment: standard widgets get parent as first argument and they keep it in `self.master` - so you don't need `self.main`. And using `self.master` you can access `parent` and using `self.master.master` can acess `grandparent` - and this can be `MainWindow` which has access to `PlotFrame`

Comment: You should also look into binding button clicks

Comment: other method is to send `PlotFrame` (`self.plot_frame`) as argument to `SaveFrame` and it will have direct access to `PlotFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Standard widgets get parent as first argument and keep it in `self.master` - you don't need `self.main`.

Using `self.master` you can access parent and using `self.master.master` can acess `grandparent`, etc. - and this `grandparent` can be your `MainWindow`.

If `MainWindow` keeps `PlotFrame` as i.e. `self.plot_frame` then `SaveFrame` may needs

```
self.master.master.plot_frame
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other method is to send `PlotFrame` (`self.plot_frame`) as argument to `OptionsFrame` and it should send it as argument to `SaveFrame` and it will have direct access to `PlotFrame`

```
class SaveFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main, plot_frame, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, *args, **kwargs)
        self.main = main
        self.plot_frame = plot_frame

class OptionsFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main, plot_frame, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, *args, **kwargs)
        self.main = main
        self.save_frame = SaveFrame(main, plot_frame)

# in MainWindow

self.plot_frame = PlotFrame(...)
self.options_frame = OptionsFrame(self, self.plot_frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.winfo_toplevel()` will get you to the main window, so the below should do what you need. I find this method much easier than working backwards through `.master`. Also, if you ever further nest your classes, you will have to add another `master` to all the `master.master.master` spots. This is going to get the top level window that the current widget belongs to, and never needs to be modified, regardless of how deep you bury a widget.

```
root = self.winfo_toplevel()
plot = root.plot_frame  #or whatever you called it
```